# React with Adonis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, adonis.js

I am trying to integrate React with Adonis Js to build an SPA. Adonis handles routing to an SPA by

```
Route.any('*', function * (request, response) {
 yield response.sendView('home')
})
```

I have done exactly that in app > Http > routes.js

Then I created a home.njk in resources > views to act as the landing page for my application. Now, I have a react file where I have created a footer. I want to handle all the links in the footer with React-router. React router handles urls to navigate to a page. However, the above code(in Adonis) says that any url (*) is going to render 'home'. That is exactly what is happening.

How do get around it? Thanks!

Comment: Mind sharing some code?

Comment: There is not much code to share actually. I appreciate your interest though. This is my first project in node.js and I choose Adonis. So I;ll be needing your assistance a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should define your api routes before the route `*`.

Adonis Router will go through your `routes.js` file and get the first route that match.

Comment: Wow! that was fairly easy. Thanks pal!